# Accessing Azure storage account from console app on OSX (Mac)

Tags: c#, macos, azure, .net-core, azure-storage

I am writing code using VS 2017 community edition for Mac and trying to access a Blob on Azure storage account. However, I am running into exceptions as shown in the code below.

The WindowsAzure.Storage version is 9.1.1

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;

namespace storageaccount
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
                CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnection"));

            //var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            //var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("images");

               //container.CreateIfNotExists(Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob);

        //Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

**Exception thrown from the afore-mentioned code:**

```
System.DllNotFoundException: fusion.dll
  at at (wrapper managed-to-native) Microsoft.Azure.NativeMethods.CreateAssemblyCache(Microsoft.Azure.NativeMethods/IAssemblyCache&,int)
  at Microsoft.Azure.NativeMethods.GetAssemblyPath (System.String name) [0x00037] in <bcbac5dcfbdd47eabe8212983b7d996d>:0
  at Microsoft.Azure.AzureApplicationSettings.GetServiceRuntimeAssembly () [0x0000d] in <bcbac5dcfbdd47eabe8212983b7d996d>:0
  at Microsoft.Azure.AzureApplicationSettings..ctor () [0x0001a] in <bcbac5dcfbdd47eabe8212983b7d996d>:0
  at Microsoft.Azure.CloudConfigurationManager.get_AppSettings () [0x0001e] in <bcbac5dcfbdd47eabe8212983b7d996d>:0
  at Microsoft.Azure.CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting (System.String name, System.Boolean outputResultsToTrace) [0x00039] in <bcbac5dcfbdd47eabe8212983b7d996d>:0
  at Microsoft.Azure.CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting (System.String name) [0x00000] in <bcbac5dcfbdd47eabe8212983b7d996d>:0
  at storageaccount.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in /Users/Projects/storageaccount/storageaccount/Program.cs:11
```

---

What's wrong with the code? I am using Nuget package to access cloud storage account. From the exception thrown it is not clear if this is supported on OSx.

Any help is appreciated.

Additional information:
I see that there are two project options in VS 2017 (for Mac) while creating a new project.
1. .Net core console app
2. .Net console app (under .Net option) - **What does this run against?**

Thanks

Comment: I can tell from experience that it works on Mac (VS 2017). Please edit your question and include the package version of `WindowsAzure.Storage` you've installed.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto  I have made the required changes.

Comment: @GauravMantri I have also added the package version for WindowsAzure.Storage version.

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to reproduce it but I am not able to find Microsoft.Azure under Nuget packages. Can you tell me which package did you install for that?

Comment: @GauravMantri I had installed Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager (v 3.2.3). Hope this helps.

Comment: I have found one workaround but that does not let me use the app.config file. When I removed the CloudConfigurationManager package and directly use the connection string, it then works. It is the CloudConfigurationManager that causes an issue on Mac. I am still looking for information on how to read app.config for .Net application on Mac.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned that Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager is **.net framework** package, it **is not compatible with .net core platform**.

> I am still looking for information on how to read app.config for .Net application on Mac

You could use the [System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager/) to do that.

```
 var storeageString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["storagestring"];
```

App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="storagestring" value ="Test string"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

**Another way** is that you could add appsettings.json to a .NET Core console app.

> All that’s required is to add the following NuGet packages and an appsettings.json file.
>
> - Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
> - Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions
> - Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json

Demo code

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
IConfigurationRoot configuration = builder.Build();
var connectionString = configuration["StorageConnection"];
Console.WriteLine(connectionString);
```

appsettings.json file:

```
{
    "StorageConnection": "Test Connection string"
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. The solution that you provided, will that work on Mac? My project is not .net core console app. In VS 2017 community edition for OSX, I am using console project under .net. There is a separate .Net core console project. I need to further research on the difference between the two.

Comment: @raringsunny. Yes, it should work on Mac. You need to create the .net  core project.  And you could get more info about .net core from this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/)

Comment: Thanks @Tom will try it out.

Comment: Do you have any update about this?  If it is useful, you could mark it as an answer.

Comment: Haven’t had a chance to try it out as yet. Will give it a try this week

Comment: one more thing, I guess I’m using a non aspnet core project (probably mono). Pls keep that also into consideration